# How to clone a VPS with OpenVZ

Tags: linux, openvz

So I recently started reselling unmanaged VPS. Now I thought it would be nice if my customers could monitor their VPS and control it via a web panel thus I planned to install OpenVZ. I now want to offer them the possibility to install preconfigured VPS templates through openVZ on which e.g. a webserver/teamspeak/wordpress is already installed. Now I have to mention that all VPS are running on different roots as I get them from a third party which you would need to consider when giving an answer. The openVZ panel is installed on the vps webspace i will be running my companys website on and will be solely acting as a vps remote control for the customer and me.

Comment: Start with the OpenVZ documentation on Templates: https://openvz.org/Application_Templates

Comment: And your question is....?

Answer (score 1):

You can create one VPS and install the basic services on it
then you can take a copy from it and save it and create new containers from that copy.
this link will be helpful https://openvz.org/Cloning_VE